# How to use IEnumerable with an object view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view that displays a user's first and last name in one model and another stores the url of their picture. All of that is connected to a view model and it gets displayed as single objects. However, I have something that requires a foreach loop, but I can't use `IEnumerable` because that throws an error.

So instead of putting them in one view model, I wanted to use a partial view that stores the `IEnumerable`, and then I call it on the regular view. But when I do that nothing appears. I'm using jQuery to render the partial view

Partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Website_friend_feature.Models.Messages>

@foreach(var message in Model)
{
    <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin"><br>
        <img src="/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
        <span class="w3-right w3-opacity">1 min</span>
        <h4>John Doe</h4><br>
        <hr class="w3-clear">
        <p> @message.Message </p>
        <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px">
            <div class="w3-half">
                <img src="/w3images/lights.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Northern Lights" class="w3-margin-bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>  Like</button> 
        <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>  Comment</button> 
    </div>
}
```

`profile.cshtml`:

```
@model Website_friend_feature.Models.ProfilePictureViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-blue-grey.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif}
</style>
</head>
<body class="w3-theme-l5">

<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-top">
 <div class="w3-bar w3-theme-d2 w3-left-align w3-large">
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-theme-d2" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-theme-d4"><i class="fa fa-home w3-margin-right"></i>Logo</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" title="News"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" title="Account Settings"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" title="Messages"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
    <button class="w3-button w3-padding-large" title="Notifications"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i><span class="w3-badge w3-right w3-small w3-green">3</span></button>     
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-card-4 w3-bar-block" style="width:300px">
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">One new friend request</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">John Doe posted on your wall</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Jane likes your post</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" title="My Account">
    <img src="/w3images/avatar2.png" class="w3-circle" style="height:23px;width:23px" alt="Avatar">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Navbar on small screens -->
<div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-theme-d2 w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-large">
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">My Profile</a>
</div>

<!-- Page Container -->
<div class="w3-container w3-content" style="max-width:1400px;margin-top:80px">    
  <!-- The Grid -->
  <div class="w3-row">
    <!-- Left Column -->
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <!-- Profile -->
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white">
        <div class="w3-container">
         <p class="w3-center"><img src=@Model.ProfilePictureVM.Picture class="w3-circle" style="height:106px;width:106px" alt="Avatar"></p>
         <h4 class="w3-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">@Model.ApplicationUserVM.FirstName @Model.ApplicationUserVM.LastName</h4>
         <h2 style="color: lightgray; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 0px; "> @@@Model.ApplicationUserVM.UserName</h2>
         
    
         <hr>
         <p><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-text-theme"></i> Designer, UI</p>
         <p><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-text-theme"></i> London, UK</p>
         <p><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-text-theme"></i> April 1, 1988</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <!-- Accordion -->
      <div class="w3-card w3-round">
        <div class="w3-white">
          <button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-button w3-block w3-theme-l1 w3-left-align"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-fw w3-margin-right"></i> My Groups</button>
          <div id="Demo1" class="w3-hide w3-container">
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
          <button onclick="myFunction('Demo2')" class="w3-button w3-block w3-theme-l1 w3-left-align"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-fw w3-margin-right"></i> My Events</button>
          <div id="Demo2" class="w3-hide w3-container">
            <p>Some other text..</p>
          </div>
          <button onclick="myFunction('Demo3')" class="w3-button w3-block w3-theme-l1 w3-left-align"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw w3-margin-right"></i> My Photos</button>
          <div id="Demo3" class="w3-hide w3-container">
         <div class="w3-row-padding">
         <br>
           <div class="w3-half">
             <img src="/w3images/lights.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-margin-bottom">
           </div>
           <div class="w3-half">
             <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-margin-bottom">
           </div>
           <div class="w3-half">
             <img src="/w3images/mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-margin-bottom">
           </div>
           <div class="w3-half">
             <img src="/w3images/forest.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-margin-bottom">
           </div>
           <div class="w3-half">
             <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-margin-bottom">
           </div>
           <div class="w3-half">
             <img src="/w3images/snow.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-margin-bottom">
           </div>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <!-- Interests --> 
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white w3-hide-small">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <p>Interests</p>
          <p>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-d5">News</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-d4">W3Schools</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-d3">Labels</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-d2">Games</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-d1">Friends</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme">Games</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-l1">Friends</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-l2">Food</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-l3">Design</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-l4">Art</span>
            <span class="w3-tag w3-small w3-theme-l5">Photos</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <!-- Alert Box -->
      <div class="w3-container w3-display-container w3-round w3-theme-l4 w3-border w3-theme-border w3-margin-bottom w3-hide-small">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-theme-l3 w3-display-topright">
          <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        </span>
        <p><strong>Hey!</strong></p>
        <p>People are looking at your profile. Find out who.</p>
      </div>
    
    <!-- End Left Column -->
    </div>
    
    <!-- Middle Column -->
    <div class="w3-col m7">
    
      <div class="w3-row-padding">
        <div class="w3-col m12">
          <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white">
            <div class="w3-container w3-padding">
              <h6 class="w3-opacity">Social Media template by w3.css</h6>
              <p contenteditable="true" class="w3-border w3-padding">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>  Post</button> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="partialMessages">
          
      </div>
      
    <!-- End Middle Column -->
    </div>
    
    <!-- Right Column -->
    <div class="w3-col m2">
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white w3-center">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
          <img src="/w3images/forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%;">
          <p><strong>Holiday</strong></p>
          <p>Friday 15:00</p>
          <p><button class="w3-button w3-block w3-theme-l4">Info</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white w3-center">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <p>Friend Request</p>
          <img src="/w3images/avatar6.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50%"><br>
          <span>Jane Doe</span>
          <div class="w3-row w3-opacity">
            <div class="w3-half">
              <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section" title="Accept"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half">
              <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-red w3-section" title="Decline"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white w3-padding-16 w3-center">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white w3-padding-32 w3-center">
        <p><i class="fa fa-bug w3-xxlarge"></i></p>
      </div>
      
    <!-- End Right Column -->
    </div>
    
  <!-- End Grid -->
  </div>
  
<!-- End Page Container -->
</div>
<br>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="w3-container w3-theme-d3 w3-padding-16">
  <h5>Footer</h5>
</footer>

<footer class="w3-container w3-theme-d5">
  <p>Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" target="_blank">w3.css</a></p>
</footer>
 


<script>

    $('#partialMessages').load("/User/DisplayMessages")
    



// Accordion
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
    x.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-theme-d1";
  } else { 
    x.className = x.className.replace("w3-show", "");
    x.previousElementSibling.className = 
    x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-theme-d1", "");
  }
}

// Used to toggle the menu on smaller screens when clicking on the menu button
function openNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else { 
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

UserController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Website_friend_feature.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Website_friend_feature.Models;

namespace Website_friend_feature.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ProfilePictureConnection _PP;

        Messages mess = new Messages();

        public UserController (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ProfilePictureConnection PP)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _PP = PP;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile(String id) 
        {
            ProfilePictureViewModel viewModel = new ProfilePictureViewModel();

            if (id == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            //var user = await viewModel.UserManagerVM.FindByNameAsync(id);
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(id);

            viewModel.ApplicationUserVM = user;

            var picture =  await _PP.ProfilePicture.FindAsync(id);
            viewModel.ProfilePictureVM = picture;

            return View(viewModel);
        }
        
        public IActionResult DisplayMessages()
        {
            var messages = _PP.Messages.ToList();

            return PartialView("_DisplayMessagesPartial", messages);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### can u just put them in one model ?

```
class yourViewModel
{
  // your prop 
  // your prop 
  List<Messages> Messages {get;set;}
}
```

in the view

```
@model yourViewModel
 .
 .
 .
 // here u can loop throw your model 
 @foreach(var message in Model.Messages)
 {
   
 }
```

Comment: yup that actually worked, I used IEnumerable but that threw errors, but setting it as a list did it no problem.